# Finding namespace URIs for lxml

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

I'm using lxml to parse XML product feeds with the following code:

```
namespace = {"sm": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"}
data = [loc.text for loc in tree.xpath("//sm:urlset/sm:url/sm:loc",namespaces=namespace)]
```

This works with the majority of feeds that I am using as an input, but I occasionally I find a feed with additional namespaces such as the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

From what I've read I would need to add the additional namespace here (xmlns:xsi I guess) to the namespace dictionary to get my xpath to work with multiple namespaces.
However, this is not a long term solution for me as I might come across other differing namespaces in the future - is there a way for me to search/detect or even delete the namespace ? The element tree always will be the same, so my xpath wouldn't change.

Thanks

Comment: I've now come across ```root.nsmap``` which helps, but is probably still going to be difficult to automate the detection of namespaces. Maybe deleting them is the way to go as I don't expect collisions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to map the `xsi` prefix; that's only there for the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute.

The difference between your current mapping and the input file is that there is an "s" in "https" in the default namespace of the XML.

To handle both namespace URIs (or really any other namespace URI that `urlset` might have) is to first get the namespace URI for the root element and then use that in your dict mapping...

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

root_ns_uri = tree.xpath("namespace-uri()")

namespace = {"sm": root_ns_uri}
data = [loc.text for loc in tree.xpath("//sm:urlset/sm:url/sm:loc", namespaces=namespace)]

print(data)
```

prints...

```py
['https://www.example.com/']
```

If `urlset` isn't always the root element, you may want to do something like this instead...

```py
root_ns_uri = tree.xpath("namespace-uri(//*[local-name()='urlset'])")
```

Comment: Not only did you spot the missing 's', but your solution is exactly what I needed. Thank you